# How can I automate an Eclipse Build + SFTP File transfer?

Tags: java, eclipse, ssh, sftp

The scenario I am facing is that I am currently developing on a Windows version of Eclipse, which suits all my developing and debugging needs. However, my testing works only on a Linux machine, and I have a plain Linux server where I run my Java code.

So, what I end up having to do is constantly :

build in Eclipse -> export as a Jar -> SFTP to my Linux Server -> SSH to run/test the file

As you can imagine, this gets very repetitive. So I'm just wondering what the best approach to do this. It would be great if you guys help me, or point me in the right direction.

Comment: Maybe you can configure Eclipse to run an External Tool task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is Eclipse truly all you're likely to need for the foreseeable future?  If there's even a chance you might need a better build technology (e.g. Gradle or Maven both of which can be run from the command line, and so let you script all of the above), I'd bite the bullet and move to it now rather than putting time into figuring out how to cobble something together that works with Eclipse.

You should be able to automate the SFTP upload and the SSH command that perform testing in a batch script that you could run from the command line.  (Exact syntax for those two commands will depend on what your SSH/SFTP client is, but if you're using something well-known like PuTTY then I'm sure there's plenty of documentation out there and you can post questions on SO if you get stuck on something.)  So really the sticking point is the process of building your JAR, and that's very easy if you move to a better build technology than Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Someone in the comments above mentioned that there is an external tool task, so can I configure Eclipse so when I build the program, it automatically creates a JAR and runs the batch files that I'll create?

Comment: I haven't used that tool so I can't comment on it. I've used Ant, Maven, and Gradle for my builds, but I've never tried (never **wanted**) to get Eclipse in the middle of my build process, for exactly the reasons you're struggling with.  Eclipse is a great IDE, but other technologies are much better build technologies, so I try to let them each do what they're best at.